# Run only test cases related to applied changes

Tags: java, testcase, infinitest

I have two versions of a Java applications. The second version is indeed resulted after applying some changes to the first version. These changes are applied automatically using a genetic programming algorithm to improve some non-functionality aspects of the program such as speed.

To become sure the behavior of system is not changed, I run test cases. However, the problem I face is that I only need to run test cases that are related to applied changes. Otherwise, it will be very time consuming if I want to run all test cases.
I know there are some continuous testing plugins such as **Infinitest** which can detect affected test cases related to applied changes, and then run those affected test cases. However, it seems these plugins do not work outside of IDE.

What I need is a pluging that I can call that in my program (my GP application) to take two versions of the program and all test cases, and then detect testcases related to changes applied in the second version. The detected test cases can then be run to find the possible bugs.

Comment: I doubt you'll find an off-the-shelf solution for that. You could roll your own by combining a version control system such as [git](http://git-scm.com), an incremental build system such as [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org) and some shell scripts to glue it together.